# Find values from array of objects using another array of ids without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to find clients' names from an array using the second array of client ids.
I would try an old-school for loop, but I think in vuejs this is not the optimal solution.

This is my main array

```js
clients = [
  {id: "1", name: "Bob"},
  {id: "2", name: "Mary"},
  {id: "3", name: "John"},
  {id: "4", name: "Petter"}
];
```

This is the array that contains only specific client ids

```js
selectedClientsIds = [1, 2, 4];
```

Comment: Please try: `console.log(clients.filter(({ id }) => selectedClientsIds.includes(+id))?.map(({ name }) => name));` and check if displays an array of names matching the `id`s in the `selectedClientsIds` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all elements in selectedClientsIds are always ids in clients, you could map the name to the ids in selectedClientsIds by finding them in clients. Like:

```
const names = selectedClientsIds.map((id) => clients.find((el) => el.id == id).name);
```

Using only `==` because the ids in clients are strings.

Answer (score 1):

*I would try an old-school for loop but I think in vue.js this is not the optimal solution.*

It's all about filtering the array, which can be done using `JavaScript` inside Vue script and then result will get bind the filtered data into the template.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clients: [
      {id: "1", name: "Bob"},
      {id: "2", name: "Mary"},
      {id: "3", name: "John"},
      {id: "4", name: "Petter"}
    ],
    selectedClientsIds: [1, 2, 4]
  },
mounted() {
    this.clients = this.clients.filter(({ id }) => this.selectedClientsIds.includes(parseInt(id)));
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id">{{ client.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```